# Modify docker image in portainer

Tags: docker, dockerfile, portainer

In portainer I created an image, using the web editor to enter the Dockerfile commands.

But I see no option to modify that image, there is no edit options.

Am I supposed to have the Dockerfile stored somewhere else, then paste it into portainer every time I've edited it?

Answer (score 4):

Portainer do not allow you to edit an image from a Dockerfile as it does not store the Dockerfile.

I'd recommend to version your Dockerfile in a CVS, this would allow to version any changes to your Dockerfile, and then update your image via the upload method inside Portainer when needed.

Comment: I thought so. Too bad. Would be nice to have this integrated, but now I know I'm not overlooking something.